# Visualforce Page Not Appearing as Lightning Action Button

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-action

I created a Visualforce page with the intent of opening it with an Action button in Salesforce Lightning. Unfortunately, when I select "Custom Visualforce", the visualforce page I created does not appear in the list picklist. All references to this issue online only note that a standard controller must be used, but my visualforce pages does so already. I also made sure that `Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app` was marked `True`.

My Visualforce code is as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Intervention__c" lightningStylesheets="true" recordSetVar="interventions" showHeader="true">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:detail inlineEdit="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

How do I update my code so that it appears as a Lightning Action Button "Custom Visualforce" option?

Comment: Where are you trying to add this button, on list view?

Comment: @Jwok is `Available For Lightning Experience` checkbox checked on VF page?